# Why does Team Flash always use a certain room for inter-dimensional travel?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

In *The Flash* (2014), the team always uses a certain room at STAR Labs for traveling between Earths, even when they are just using Cisco's powers. However, he is capable of creating inter-dimensional breaches anywhere (e.g. he does it from the testing field in 3x08 *Invasion!*).

Why do they insist on having a dedicated room for inter-dimensional travel? Best I can tell, the room isn't used for anything else on a regular basis.

Comment: Why does Star Trek use transporter rooms when site-to-site transporting exists? Sometimes having a place with a purpose is nice to have. For that matter, what about the times when the Team needs a breach when Cisco isn't around? The tech in the room can probably handle that.

Comment: IIRC, they needed some equipment at the beginning of the season 2 to support Cisco's powers and open breaches to other Earths. It may not be as useful as before since Cisco can vibe through dimension freely, but why removing it? It may be useful for others (like Wells contacting the Council of Wells for example). Didn't Wells-2 arrive in that room at the beginning of the Season 4? It seems to me that it is used as a doorway for friends from other dimensions.